# Why can I call c# functions without brackets?

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
class HelloWorld {
  static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine(first());
    Console.WriteLine(second);
  }
  private static string first() => "first";
  private static string second => "second";
}
```

```
    private string first() => "first";
    private string second => "second";
    void Sample()
    {
        print(second);   // no err
        print(second()); // but
        
        print(first()); // no err
        print(first);   // but
    }
```

brackets are optional syntactic sugar?
why are the field and the function so similar?

Comment: Those are `properties` not `functions`

Comment: What's the difference? They're the same, here's the code.

Comment: See [expression-bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) especially [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#methods) vs [read-only properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#read-only-properties)

Comment: "brackets are optional syntactic sugar?" Eeeehm, no. You need them for methods, but not for fields. Those two are completely different things - even if you can use lambds for both of them does not make them equal.

Comment: They're so similar because properties are a way to encapsulate field access with methods, so it's transparent to the caller if an actual field is used (or, as in the case of `second`, a method that returns a constant value). The reason a method can be "used" without parentheses (but not a property) is not because they're optional sugar, but because C# has a notion of "method groups" with implicit conversion to delegates. The output of `print(first)` and `print(first())` is wildly different.

Comment: My point is this:
what if we step back from the conceptual intentions of language, look back and see what tools we have and how else we can use them?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up things.

`first` is a method. There is syntactic sugar involved.

This

```cs
private string first() => "first";
```

Becomes

```cs
private string first()
{
    return "first";
}
```

As it is a method, it may have arguments. You could do something like

```cs
private void HelloWorld(string greeting) => Console.WriteLine($"{greeting}, world !");
```

That becomes

```cs
private void HelloWorld(string greeting)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{greeting}, world !");

    // no return here because of void
}
```

`second` is a property. There is also syntactic sugar involved.

This

```cs
private string second => "second";
```

Becomes

```cs
private string second
{
    get
    {
         return "second";
    }
}
```

Comment: it's like you can program with a functional style focus?
it looks like

Comment: I think it's worthusing when returning the result of another direct call `private int Foo() => Bar()` or a computed value `private string Fullname => $"{FirstName} {LastName}"`

Comment: @koplenov Methods should be used for operations on the object that change state, or calling external resources. Properties should be used to get or set values in the item. The user should expect to get the same value last set by a property on an instance.

Comment: Property, however, is syntactic sugar for generating two methods and one variable, right?

Comment: Yes? But that thinking makes almost everything in a language syntactic sugar. You can do almost everything on a less abstract level. If you then call it "sugar" or not is just then relative to something you call for yourself the "norm". Would you call loops syntactic sugar? You can almost always replace them by if and goto.

Comment: .. and its just one or two methods with possible special visibilities. There doesn't need to be a backing field. Even  in your examples its just a getter without backing fields.

Comment: [1] On the one hand, yes, I will. C# in 2022 is the Nemerle/Nitra language in 2008. (roughly speaking, [string interpolation was brought into c# from there, as well as many features] the language by the way also runs on top of dotnet)
The language is simple, but extensible with macros and what big companies have been adding for years to the language is done in a couple of lines in others.


I don't understand why people are disliking this question.
On a deeper level, it's about philosophy and art.

Comment: [2] Lately I've been looking more at the functional elements component. I liked the philosophy of the Clojure language. I saw how problems were solved in it and wanted to compare experiences with different languages.
Going back to c#, I also want to revisit its constituents.
I asked a question here to get an answer from de wanderers like me - it's not about basic syntax.